# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to start after device full error

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I recently had a disk or device full error while downloading torrents. I cleared some disk space but laptop will not restart ubuntu 20.04. The splash screen displays but the freezes at -

5.857051 Bluetooth: hcio: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

Which means nothing to me

I can boot from USB drive but I really want to get existing system running rather than reinstall. Can anyone assist please.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it - booted from usb stick - try Ubuntu - opened system drive and deleted everything I did not need. It seems the drive was still full. Now I have some free space it boots OK

Just as an aside - some people may not be aware that apparently, Transmission torrent downloader for Ubuntu seems to 'reserve' the complete space required to download a file, this is what caused me to inadvertently run out of space - I assumed space would be used up as files downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to this, I had the the same error but the issue was not disk space and instead a BIOS boot option I had changed when I was working with a  Raspberry Pi.

The error message is not the likely culprit for the error but simply the last message present.

**The issue for me was a modified secure boot configuration. I reset the secure boot options to setup defaults and was able to boot back in.**